# Zsh autocomplete from the middle of filename

Tags: zsh

is it possible that zsh complete the whole file name from partial words of correct filename ? For example, there are (helloABC, helloabc, helloworld) under this folder, and I want to type only (oab + tab) to get (helloABC, helloabc.)

Comment: I'm running oh-my-zsh, and it appears to work.

Comment: Here is another solution, that was written in a similar topic -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390849/197796

Answer (score 34):

Yes this is possible. It can be enabled in the *zsh completion system*.

Adding these lines to your `.zshrc` will give you this feature:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' '+l:|=* r:|=*'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

- `_completer` gives normal completion behaviour
- `'m:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' '+l:|=* r:|=*'` takes care of case-insensive matching and that matching may occur on both sides of the current word (that is matching from the middle part of a filename).

**Note:** Some of these or similar lines may already be in your `~/.zshrc`. In that case you may have to edit them:

- if not already there `_complete` has to be added to the line starting with the definition for `completer`
- If already present the rule for case-insensitivity might look different, for example `m:{A-Za-z}={a-zA-Z}`, which you can either be replaced or left as is.

  `+l:|=* r:|=*` has to come immediatelly after the rule for case-insensitivity (it may also work if there are only rules starting with `+` between those two rules, but I did only check some basic combinations, which worked)

Comment: This solution didn't work for me (zsh 5.7.1, no oh-my-zsh). But adding the line as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259511/236516) to my .zsh worked.